# If 'dnssec-enable' is obsolete and must be removed, what is the alternative when creating a DNS server on BIND 9?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to set up a Forwarding DNS server, using this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-16-04. I've followed all the steps and inserted the line

```
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation yes;
```

However, when running:

```
sudo named-checkconf
```

It's telling me that

> option 'dnssec-enable' is obsolete and should be removed

Therefore, what's the alternative? I've tried to search it on Goolge and make a quick look on Bind 9 doc but doesn't say anything about it. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: You might want to start by explaining which version of bind you are using... you can find full explanations of DNSSEC with bind at https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.19/doc/arm/html/chapter7.html for example...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Bind9 as you can see in the title. But the link to the chapter doesn't say nothing about 'dnssec-enable = yes;' being obsolete nor a alternative to it...

Comment: "I'm using Bind9" That is not a version.There is at least 3 major bind9 versions out there right now... See https://www.isc.org/download/

Comment: "But the link to the chapter doesn't say nothing about 'dnssec-enable = yes;' being obsolete nor a alternative to it..." Because it was made obsolete long ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version [9.16.0](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_16/notes.html#id77) the `dnssec-enable` option was made obsolete and in [9.18.0](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_18/notes.html#id14) the option was entirely removed.

From the [9.16.0 release notes](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_16/notes.html#id77):

> The `dnssec-enable` option has been obsoleted and no longer has any effect. DNSSEC responses are always enabled if signatures and other DNSSEC data are present. [GL #866]

Ie, the change is that there is no longer a way to disable the fundamental handling of DNSSEC data. You can still enable/disable validation through [`dnssec-validation`](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_16/reference.html#boolean-options) though.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that release notes contained info on changes made to the documentation. Before I had just Ctrl+F on the official doc and that's why I didn't find a thing for 'dnssec-enable yes;'